# Get Last in and last Out from spesific door only MYSQL

Tags: mysql

This is the scenario. I have a MYSQL table for attendance which have records as below:

```
   Id   DateTime             Door   Employee_id
    1   2016-01-01 08:00:00  In     100
    2   2016-01-01 09:00:00  Out    100
    3   2016-01-01 09:11:00  Enter  100
    4   2016-01-01 09:12:00  Exit   100
    5   2016-01-01 09:15:00  In     100
    6   2016-01-01 09:30:00  In     100
    7   2016-01-01 10:00:00  Out    100
    8   2016-01-01 11:00:00  In     100
    9   2016-01-01 12:00:00  In     100
   10   2016-01-01 13:00:00  In     100
   11   2016-01-01 13:30:00  Out    100
   10   2016-01-01 14:00:00  Out    100
   12   2016-01-01 15:00:00  In     100
```

I want the output as Last Clock In and Last Clock Out from 'In' and 'Out' door only as shown below. If there are no clock out after last clock in, just ignore the clock in. If there are any other door besides 'In' and 'Out' also ignore.

```
Id   Clock In             Clock Out             Employee Id
 1   2016-01-01 08:00:00  2016-01-01 09:00:00   100
 2   2016-01-01 09:30:00  2016-01-01 10:00:00   100
 3   2016-01-01 13:00:00  2016-01-01 14:00:00   100
```

I get stuck on this on for many days already. Kindly help me out guys. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the id column. Shurely shome mishtake

Comment: id column is only a primary key which is auto-increment when new records inserted.

Comment: Not in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution with demo using your data.

SQL:

```
-- data
create table attendance(Id int, DateTime datetime, Door char(20), Employee_id int);
INSERT INTO attendance VALUES
(    1,   '2016-01-01 08:00:00',  'In', 100),
(    2,   '2016-01-01 09:00:00',  'Out', 100),
(    3,   '2016-01-01 09:11:00',  'Enter', 100),
(    4,   '2016-01-01 09:12:00',  'Exit', 100),
(    5,   '2016-01-01 09:15:00',  'In', 100),
(    6,   '2016-01-01 09:30:00',  'In', 100),
(    7,   '2016-01-01 10:00:00',  'Out', 100),
(    8,   '2016-01-01 11:00:00',  'In', 100),
(    9,   '2016-01-01 12:00:00',  'In', 100),
(   10,   '2016-01-01 13:00:00',  'In', 100),
(   11,   '2016-01-01 13:30:00',  'Out', 100),
(   10,   '2016-01-01 14:00:00',  'Out', 100),
(   12,   '2016-01-01 15:00:00',  'In', 100);
SELECT * FROM attendance;

-- SQL needed:
SELECT  @id:=@id+1 Id,
        MAX(IF(Door = 'In', DateTime, NULL)) `Check In`,
        MAX(IF(Door = 'Out', DateTime, NULL)) `Check Out`,
        Employee_id
FROM (SELECT *, 
            CASE WHEN (Door != 'Out' AND @last_door = 'Out')
                 THEN @group_num:=@group_num+1
                 ELSE @group_num END door_group,
            @last_door:=Door
        FROM attendance JOIN (SELECT @group_num:=1, @last_door := NULL) a
      ) t JOIN (SELECT @id:=0 ) b
GROUP BY t.door_group
HAVING SUM(Door = 'In') > 0 AND SUM(Door = 'Out') > 0;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM attendance;
:+------+---------------------+-------+-------------+
| Id   | DateTime            | Door  | Employee_id |
+------+---------------------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | 2016-01-01 08:00:00 | In    |         100 |
|    2 | 2016-01-01 09:00:00 | Out   |         100 |
|    3 | 2016-01-01 09:11:00 | Enter |         100 |
|    4 | 2016-01-01 09:12:00 | Exit  |         100 |
|    5 | 2016-01-01 09:15:00 | In    |         100 |
|    6 | 2016-01-01 09:30:00 | In    |         100 |
|    7 | 2016-01-01 10:00:00 | Out   |         100 |
|    8 | 2016-01-01 11:00:00 | In    |         100 |
|    9 | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 | In    |         100 |
|   10 | 2016-01-01 13:00:00 | In    |         100 |
|   11 | 2016-01-01 13:30:00 | Out   |         100 |
|   10 | 2016-01-01 14:00:00 | Out   |         100 |
|   12 | 2016-01-01 15:00:00 | In    |         100 |
+------+---------------------+-------+-------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- SQL needed:
mysql> SELECT  @id:=@id+1 Id,
    ->         MAX(IF(Door = 'In', DateTime, NULL)) `Check In`,
    ->         MAX(IF(Door = 'Out', DateTime, NULL)) `Check Out`,
    ->         Employee_id
    -> FROM (SELECT *,
    ->             CASE WHEN (Door != 'Out' AND @last_door = 'Out')
    ->                  THEN @group_num:=@group_num+1
    ->                  ELSE @group_num END door_group,
    ->             @last_door:=Door
    ->         FROM attendance JOIN (SELECT @group_num:=1, @last_door := NULL) a
    ->       ) t JOIN (SELECT @id:=0 ) b
    -> GROUP BY t.door_group
    -> HAVING SUM(Door = 'In') > 0 AND SUM(Door = 'Out') > 0;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| Id   | Check In            | Check Out           | Employee_id |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|    1 | 2016-01-01 08:00:00 | 2016-01-01 09:00:00 |         100 |
|    2 | 2016-01-01 09:30:00 | 2016-01-01 10:00:00 |         100 |
|    3 | 2016-01-01 13:00:00 | 2016-01-01 14:00:00 |         100 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks for the code Dylan, it works when using this sample of table. But when I changed it to different name of column and different sample data, it seems not working. Correct me if I'm wrong. Here is the sample I use. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e37ab

Comment: where is the 'In' and 'Out'?

Comment: I replaced the 'In' and 'Out' with another varchar which represent them respectively. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e37ab/2

Comment: oh, now I found why. I search for wrong date range just now. Thanks for the amazing answer. Will try it out at my local mysql. :)

Comment: tested in my local mysql, but I wonder why I need to run query two times to get all the rows? If I run the query at first time, it only return a row. Do you ever encounter this kind of problem?

Comment: slightly update the post, by removing '@last_door := NULL' to inside join. pls update and try again.

Comment: after removing '@last_door := NULL' , still having the same issue. Need to run the query two times to get all rows.

Comment: not remove, but put at `FROM attendance JOIN (SELECT @group_num:=1, @last_door := NULL) a`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Select @x := -1;
Select @pDate := NOW();

SELECT all2.link, all2.prevD as 'Clock In', all2.DateTime as 'Clock Out'
FROM
 (SELECT
    DateTime, id, Door, @x:=@x AS prev,
    if(@x > 0, @x, -1) as link,
    @x:=IF(door = 'In', id, if(door = 'Out', id, -1)) AS cure,
    @pDate as prevD,
    @pDate:=IF(door = 'In', DateTime, NULL) AS pDate,
    @x:=IF(door = 'Out', -1, @x) as reseter
FROM
    test.doors) as all2
WHERE all2.link != -1 AND all2.Door = 'Out'
```

In fact there is one bug that is:
'I couldn't recognize the last `Out` state, So I wish you will try to solve it, I do not have enough time.

**Best wishes**